# How to set RTL direction of translation using i18next?

Tags: reactjs, i18next, bidirectional

I have a text with "mixed directions" parts, that means that part of the sentence should be RTL and other should be LTR.

For example:

```
{
  "CC_LAST_DIGITS": "מס׳ כרטיס: **** **** **** 1234"
}
```

In the example the main layout is in **RTL**, and the browser renders the asterisks **after** the 4 digits. They should be rendered a the front of the 4 digits.

How can I force LTR in I18next?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found out that there is [direction marks](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H34.html) which can be used in order to switch text direction in unicode usage.

> left-to-right mark: ‎ or ‎ (U+200E)

> right-to-left mark: ‏ or ‏ (U+200F)

In order to fix my translation text you need to add a unicode of the proper direction before the asterisks:

```
{
  "CC_LAST_DIGITS": "מס׳ כרטיס:\u200E **** **** **** 1234"
}
```